# XSLT: Check if XML element has parent in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've browsed many examples here on SO, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. There are many examples to match an element that has a specific parent. However, I don't want to match a specific parent, I just want to know if it has a parent at all.

So for the xml here:

```
<foo>
    <bar/>
</foo>
<bar/>
```

with the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="[test here]">
            ..do something..
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

how do I simply test if the `<bar>` element has a parent or is has none?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard XPath format would be a selection for `ancestor::*`, which you can easily find if you look at XSLT/XPath tutorials relating to parents and ancestors. I assume you first googled for that and none of them worked, so: what have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but with the exception of the root, don't all elements have a parent?

Comment: All elements have a parent except the root.  Your XML sample is not valid as it has two roots, `foo` and `bar`. This is not allowed in well-formed XML.

Comment: You are correct, I have made some considerable mistakes in this question. My apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This input:**

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

**To this script:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="parent::*">Parent: </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>No Parent: </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Yields this output:**

```
No Parent: foo
Parent: bar
Parent: baz
```

Note: Your sample input file is not well-formed and cannot serve as the input to an XSLT transformation because it has two roots.

Comment: Yes you are correct - I made a mistake. I have two root elements. My intention was just to show that I have an element, `bar`, which is sometimes appears at different hierarchies in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a wildcard name test on the parent axis: `test="parent::*"`